# Is _diffs folder removed automatically when deploying Liferay theme?

Tags: themes, liferay-theme, liferay-6.2

I am investigating some problems in a deployed liferay theme, I am not able to find the _diffs folder there, so

1-is it always removed when deploying or the deployment manager did something wrong or it's the developers's decision ?

2-Is there any consequences to its absence @ run time if the code inside it is already copied to the folders under WEB-INF ?

Answer (score 0):

The `_diffs` folder is no longer needed after the build process.

Comment: ok, so is it removed automatically when deployment is done or manually?

Comment: Not sure if it's removed automatically or not.